# Cut out first pattern in string

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to remove the first value from a string...

```
$string = "`"JSteward`",`"43518790`",`"512`",`"JSteward@mystuff.com`""

$fixedString = $string -replace "^`"[*]`",", ""

Write-Host $fixedString
```

The output results in:

```
"JSteward","43518790","512","JSteward@mystuff.com"
```

The output I want:

```
"43518790","512","JSteward@mystuff.com"
```

can anyone tell me what's wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified to match correct solution that this helped solve, to keep the answer clean.

> $fixedString = $string -replace '^"[^"]*",', ""

Basically it reads like this. From the beginning of the string, match double quotes and then match anything that is not double quotes, then match double quotes and a comma.

Comment: Gave a parsing error on the 2nd `^`. I just had to make one small change (`'^"[^"]*",', ""`) and it works! Thanks :)

Comment: Great please mark the answer correct and up vote to indicate usefulness. I've updated the answer to include your solution.